# unable to get the data from pytest.fixture instead getting the data location

Tags: python, pycharm, integration-testing, pytest

i am testing in pytest.
here is my code

## file1.py

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
     parser.addoption('--uid')

@pytest.fixture
def login_id(request,pytestconfig):
    user_id = pytestconfig.getoption('--uid')

    return user_id
```

what it does is take the cli argument  in pytest

## file2.py

```
@pytest.fixture 
def func(): 
      login(login_id)
      return session()
```

when i am performing the test on a module which require the session to be created login_id is giving me data as

> < function login_id at 0x00000000092F79D8>

i am unable to get this data , how to get the value which i am passing in cli argument.

i am using pycharm, python3.5 .

cli parameter as `--uid username`

i am not getting the username in `login` fucntion but instead getting the location of data.

thanks and regards

Comment: Not sure if I understand what you're trying to do, but your `login_id` is a function, not a simple variable with value. You're not calling it so getting the string repr of it I guess.

Comment: it's a pytest fixture  feature, pytest.fixture is handle this all. as a function .

Comment: yes, looks like it. Then your func definition should be like this if you're going to use it like a fixture: `def test_func(login_id): your code` .

Comment: @sehrob thanks , it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a fixture's value in another fixture, just pass it as a parameter:

```
@pytest.fixture
def login_id(request):
    ...
    return ...

@pytest.fixture 
def func(login_id): 
      login(login_id)
      return session()
```

Suggestion aside: you don't need the `pytestconfig` fixture since you are already using `request`. You can get the config via `request.config` in the `login_id` fixture:

```
@pytest.fixture
def login_id(request):
    user_id = request.config.getoption('--uid')
    return user_id
```

Comment: i tried this one but i am still getting the value `<function login_id at 0x00000000092F49D8>` not the argument i am giving, i am open to use other thing instead in pytest

Comment: If you did try the code I gave you and the fixture would be not found, you should get another error message from `pytest`, complaining about a fixture being not found. Try removing the `__pycache__` directories; otherwise, double-check your code.